# Parser BS4 write to file

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm study python and have a task. 
I have to write the scraping results to file, but there are some errors. Each string in the result file as "None", but when I output such results to console it works right.

In function takeText

```
def takeText(self,nameArticleFile):
        x=input("Введите слово по которому нужно отыскать статьи\n")
        for titlesearch in self.soup1.findAll('item'):
            if titlesearch.find(string=re.compile(x)):
                self.zagsearch.append(titlesearch.find(string=re.compile(x)))
                self.urlsearch.append(titlesearch.find('guid',text=True))
        print('Статьи в которых есть вхождение слова:')
        for s in range(len(self.zagsearch)):
            print(self.zagsearch[s].string)
        print('Ссылки на статьи в которых найдено слово:')
        for a in range(len(self.urlsearch)):
            print(self.urlsearch[a].string)
        for b in range(len(self.urlsearch)):
            self.response1=urllib.request.urlopen(self.urlsearch[b].string)
            self.soup2=BeautifulSoup(self.response1.read())
            with open(nameArticleFile, "w") as file:
                for i in self.soup2.findAll('p'):
                    file.write(str(self.searchP.append(i)))
            for i in range(len(self.searchP)):
                print(self.searchP[i].string)
```

Comment: `append()` always return `None` - so `file.write(....append(i))` have to give `None` in file. You have to write `i`, not `append(i)`. Besides if you display `print(self.searchP[i].string)` and you see results then do the same with file `write(self.searchP[i].string)`

Answer (score 0):

`append()` always returns `None` so `write(...append())` means `write(None)`

You have to write `i` (or `i.string)`, not `append(i)`

```
with open(nameArticleFile, "w") as file:
    for i in self.soup2.findAll('p'):

        # display and write `i`
        print(i.string)
        file.write(i.string)

        # add to list
        self.searchP.append(i)

        # or  display and write last item from list
        #print(self.searchP[-1].string)
        #file.write(self.searchP[-1].string)
```

---

In Python instead of `range(len(self.searchP))` we use

```
for item in self.searchP:
     print(items.string)
```